# Google App scripts only work when manually triggered not for time trigger when refreshing the data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I was trying to write a script that automatically refreshes all the data every day at 1-2 pm.
The refresh works fine when I run it however when I am using triggers it does not seem to work.
Realize that the error that I received was about `BigQuery error: VPC Service Controls: Request is prohibited by organization's policy. vpcServiceControlsUniqueIdentifier:`

Here is my code:

```
function refreshAndBackup() {

  try {
    SpreadsheetApp.enableBigQueryExecution();
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/');
    const dataSheet = ss.getDataSourceSheets()[0];
    ss.refreshAllDataSources();
    console.log(`Last refresh time: ${dataSheet} ${dataSheet.getStatus().getLastRefreshedTime()}`);
    console.log('Refresh completed successfully.');

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error occurred:', error);
  }
}
```

Even in the execution log it says run successfully. However, the data is still not the latest one.
Hope I can get some ideas.
Thanks
[image]

[image]

The image shows that the time trigger works fine without any error however the last update time is the one that I manually triggered, I just changed the function name, and everything else is the same.

Comment: Where is the example with the trigger?

Comment: I have added a snapshot of the trigger. Thanks

Comment: Exact copy of [Google App scripts only work when manually triggered not for time trigger when refreshing the data](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/173055/269219). See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Comment: I have deleted that post, will you be able to help me out with this question?

Comment: In the [Sheets forum thread](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/246037801?msgid=246375287), you mention another error: `BigQuery error: VPC Service Controls: Request is prohibited by organization's policy. vpcServiceControlsUniqueIdentifier:`. It may help if you [edit] the question to include the full error message, and any other relevant details.

Comment: Are you using the same Google account when you run the trigger manually in the script editor, and when you set up the trigger to run it automatically?

Comment: Yes, both manually in the script editor and the trigger are set up using my own account. I use my account to authorize the trigger as well and the owner is me.